# calling a synchronous function asynchronously in django-graphene mutation

Tags: django, graphql, python-asyncio, graphene-python, graphene-django

My mutation contains a function which calls an API to send SMS.
Since this function's execution may take some time, and its result doesn't have anything to do with what the mutation returns (It does not have to be send back to the client); I prefer to run it asynchronously. So that the mutation gets executed as fast as possible.

Here's my code:

```
class MyMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        phone = graphene.String(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, root, info, phone):
        ...
        ...
        myfunction() #The client should not wait for this function's execution. 
        return MyMutation(success=True)
```

note: myfunction **is NOT an async** function.
And I prefer to keep it that way.

I couldn't find a proper way to do this in django-graphene's docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
I wanted to see if there was any other way than using packages like celery as you mentioned.

So I installed celery with redis and made some initial configurations.
I declared myfunction in a file called tasks.py
and called it from the mutation:

```
from .tasks import myfunction
class MyMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        phone = graphene.String(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, root, info, phone):
        ...
        ...
        myfunction().delay() #now this function is called asynchronously 
        return MyMutation(success=True)
```

Everything works smoothly.